# How to run/test renovate bot locally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, renovate

Before I configure renovate to work with my Azure pipeline, how can I run npx renovate locally to check does it work as I expect and does my config file is well configured. I'm trying with **npx renovate --platform local** command.

My project is based on JS/React so I have installed renovate via npm.

I'm getting warn message: **Unknown error fetching default owner preset**

this is my config.js file: `const config = {
extends: ['config:recommended'],
};

export default config;`

I've found inside renovate documentation something related to local presets but not sure how can I configure or set it.

documentation:
*Local presets¶
Renovate also supports local presets, e.g. presets that are hosted on the same platform as the target repository. This is especially helpful in self-hosted scenarios where public presets cannot be used. Local presets are specified either by leaving out any prefix, e.g. owner/name, or explicitly by adding a local> prefix, e.g. local>owner/name. Renovate will determine the current platform and look up the preset from there.*

info from console:

> INFO: Repository finished (repository=local)
> "cloned": undefined,
> "durationMs": 434  INFO: Renovate is exiting with a non-zero code due to the following logged errors
> "loggerErrors": [
> {
> "name": "renovate",
> "level": 50,
> "logContext": "LHh5xmukB832iVr6l_qFS",
> "repository": "local",
> "err": {
> "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '')",
> "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '')\n

this is my renovate.json file:

```
{
  "onboardingConfig": { "extends": ["config:recommended"] },
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchPackageNames": ["*"],
      "automerge": false
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  platform: 'azure',
  endpoint: 'https://dev.azure.com/myend-point/',
  token: process.env.TOKEN,
  hostRules: [
    {
      hostType: 'npm',
      matchHost: 'pkgs.dev.azure.com',
      username: 'apikey',
      password: process.env.TOKEN,
    },
  ],
  repositories: ['my repository'],
};
```

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: Enable more logs maybe? There's a log level variable that you can set to DEBUG. Maybe it'll give you more info about the error.

Comment: @GaëlJ question has been updated with more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the `renovate.json` only then you can use the following command to validate it locally.

```
npx --package renovate -c 'renovate-config-validator'
```

You could automate it and put the following action in the github actions to make it as part of your CI/CD workflow.

```
name: Renovate

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
    - opened
    - edited
    - synchronize
    paths:
    - .github/workflows/renovate.yaml
    - renovate.json

jobs:
  validate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Renovate Config Validation
      uses: rinchsan/renovate-config-validator@v0.0.12
      with:
        pattern: 'renovate.json'
```